# Pyspark don't receive data from port using socket from Binance

Tags: python, sockets, pyspark

I have a script that takes a stream from binance and create a socket with symbols and price change on port 9009.

```
import json
import socket
import websocket

def on_open(ws,conn):
  print('opened connection')

def on_message(ws, message,connexion):
    message = json.loads(message)
    for data in message:
        symbol = data['s']
        price_change_percent = float(data['P'])
        kline_data = {"symbol": symbol, "price_change_percent": price_change_percent}
        json_data = json.dumps(kline_data)
        print(f"Datos enviados a través de la conexión de socket: {json_data}")
        result = connexion.send(json_data.encode())
        print(f"Resultado de la llamada a conn.send(): {result}")

def get_data(con):
    socket_address = "wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/!ticker@arr"
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(socket_address, on_open=on_open, on_close=on_close, on_message=lambda ws, msg: on_message(ws, msg, connexion=con))
    print("Connecting to Binance WebSocket...")
    ws.run_forever()

TCP_IP = "localhost"
TCP_PORT = 9009
conn = None
# Creamos un socket  y  lo vinculamos a la dirección IP y el puerto especificados mediante el método bind()
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
# Ponemos el socket en modo de escucha mediante el método listen()
s.listen(1)
print("Waiting for TCP connection...")
conn, addr = s.accept()
print("Connected... Starting getting klines.")
get_data(conn)
```

I have another script for catching this data using pyspark

```
# Importar las librerías:
from pyspark import SparkConf,SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.sql import Row,SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import json

# crea un contexto spark con la configuración anterior
sc = SparkContext("local[*]","binanceTickerStream")
sc.setLogLevel("WARN")

# crea el Contexto Streaming desde el contexto spark visto arriba con intervalo de 2 segundos
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 5)

# lee data del puerto 9009
tickerStream = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost",9009)

# Realizamos alguna transformación o acción, por ejemplo contar la cantidad de elementos recibidos
count = tickerStream.count()

# Imprimimos el resultado por consola
count.pprint()

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

The first script i think that works properly, but the second, only prints timestamps:
[image]

How can i get on the second script, the highest price that are running on the first cript?? I don't know where is the error.
Thank you

Comment: Are you parsing the JSON correctly?

Comment: I think so, but this is one of my doubts about the problem.